# Mule publish subscribe

Tags: mule

A message published to a topic is subscribed by Multiple subscribers. In my case the publisher is publishing to a topic and subscriber message flows are triggered. Is there a way to notify the publisher that all the subscribers have **consumed the message** and **finished processing the message**.I am not sure how this needs to be done.Any suggestions on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a response queue where each subscriber send a message when they're done processing.

Use an aggregator to consume the message of this response queue and perform the desired action when all the response messages have been aggregated.

This will require setting Mule correlation headers (`MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE` and `MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_ID`) to allow the aggregator to work but is feasible.

Comment: Using this route, it would need to be known ahead of time of many subscribers there are though (correct)? Meaning you would need to know what to set the Group Size to.

Comment: If I add new subscribers to the topic I need to change the correlation group size any other way of doing this

Comment: Yes, something somewhere needs to know the number of subscribers otherwise it's impossible to know if they've all done processing.